# Too slow to select application to open a download file in Firefox

Tags: firefox, evince

For unknown reason, some of downloaded pdf files in Firefox are opened by default by gedit, and some are by default by evince.

For those which will be opened by default by gedit, I want to select the executable file `/usr/bin/evince` when I initiate the download. But it always takes very long to show the many files under `/usr/bin/`, and sometimes forever. (See the picture below. Actually it should be "Open with" selected, not "Save File".).

I wonder what I can do to make it faster to select evince to open a pdf file when finish downloading it?

Thanks.

[image]

In my Firefox preferences:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked assigned "Applications" in "Firefox Preferences?"

Comment: In Applications in Preferences, all pdf related items have "Always Ask" as their actions. But I don't know why some pdf files are opened with evince, and some with gedit. I want to change that all to be either opened with evince or saved somewhere, but there is no option for that.

Comment: Note: There is a limitation for PDF where if the URL is served as application/octet-stream, or set with a content-disposition: attachment header, it will force downloading of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you have 4 PDF entries but you may wish to try setting prefs in Firefox to match this:

[image: PDF-Firefox]

PDF files open with evince after making this adjustment. After opening with evince you can choose "Save a copy" from the evince File menu.

[image: Mozilla Manual]

To choose a local or web application to handle a type, select the application from the drop-down menu. If you want a local application that is not in the menu to handle the type, select Use other… from the drop-down menu and point Firefox to its location.

Further support for firefox is available at https://support.mozilla.org

Comment: But I would like to be asked whether to open them or save them somewhere. So I want to  keep "Always Ask". My post was asking when I download a pdf file and chose to open the file, how I can choose evince instead of gedit to open the file. Choosing the executable file of evince takes forever.

Comment: @Tim Evince opens on my system in less than a second and I have the option to save the file from there. Thinking outside the box, perhaps trimming your PDF entries down to the default quantity of 1 would reduce the amount of time your system thrashes around trying to determine what you want?

Comment: You missed my problem. The default application which Firefox chooses to open a pdf file is sometimes evince and sometimes gedit, and this is shown when I choose "Open with". When it shows gedit, I would like to select evince, so I need to open /usr/bin/ to select /usr/bin/evince (see my first picture). But since there are too many files under /usr/bin, it takes too long to show them for me to choose /usr/bin/evince.

Comment: @Tim. My apologies I thought you were trying to solve a specific Ubuntu problem. If your hardware is slow you may wish to consider an upgrade....

Comment: I am not saying my hardware is slow either...

Comment: Have you tried removing the extra PDF entries? The only reason I can come up with for your inconsistent results is that. Please read my last comment under your question.